# Correcting a blemish to do avodah in the Bais Hamikdash

Tags: kohen-priest, beis-hamikdash

I was learning Hilchos Bias Hamikdash chapter 8 which discusses the specific blemishes of a human which disqualify a kohen fron doing avodah in the mikdash. One of the blemishes is a Unibrow(one long eyebrow) . Can a kohen with one long eye brow shave the middle and now will not have a blemish ,or do we say that this kohen has an intrinsic blemish?

This question is asking on all of those blemishes, if one does a surgery to correct then do we say that now they can do the avodah. I wanted to bring a proof from halacha 11 which discusses a kohen which has a 6th finger and if he cuts it off then he is kasher to do avodah(if the finger didnt have a bone). So we see that this can be corrected ,so maybe it applies to all blemishes. However, the Rambam does not give this advice for many of the other blemishes.  Does anyone discuss this question?